# Appending element from an object array with inner object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Good day everyone I would like to ask what's wrong with my code. Here's the situation. Given that I have an object like this:

```
var nav = [
    {name:"home", subNav: []},
    {name:"shop",
     subNav: [
       {name:"inner1",  subNav: []},
       {name:"inner2", 
        subNav: [ 
            {name:"inner3",  subNav: []},
            {name:"inner4",  subNav: []}
        ]}
     ]},
    {name:"about", subNav: []},
    {name:"contact", subNav: []},
];
```

Append each object's name to an html element but if its subnav has a length map it then append it too and so on and so forth. What I have for now is something like this.

```js
$('.nav').html('');
var navs = "";

var nav = [
    {name:"home", subNav: []},
    {name:"shop",
     subNav: [
    {name:"inner1",  subNav: []},
    {name:"inner2", 
        subNav: [ 
            {name:"inner3",  subNav: []},
            {name:"inner4",  subNav: []}
        ]}
     ]},
    {name:"about", subNav: []},
    {name:"contact", subNav: []},
];

nav.forEach(function(n) {
  if (n.subNav.length > 0) {

    navs = '<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">' + n.name + '<span class="caret"></span></a>';
    navs += '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
    //map subnav of first parent
    n.subNav.map(function(i) {
      navs += '<li><a href="/' + i.name + '">' + i.name + '</a></li>';
    });
    navs += '</ul>';
    navs += '</li>';

    //Edit
    //this is where I will use getSubnav(n,ele)

  } else {
    navs = '<li class=""><a href="/' + n.name + '">' + n.name + '</a></li>';
  }

  $('.nav').append(navs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     WebSiteName
    </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I want the inner2 menu to be the same as its parent with a dropdown because it has an array inside of it. Tried to use a function that repeats itself so that it would call itself until there's no more array in the subNavs and pass in the nav object and the element to be appended like this: `getSubnav(n,navs)` <- inserted in the if statement.

```
function getSubnav(nav,ele){


    ele ='<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">' + nav.name+ '<span class="caret"></span></a>';
    ele +='<ul class="dropdown-menu">';

    nav.subNav.map(function(i){
       ele += '<li><a href="/' + i.name+ '">' + i.name + '</a></li>';
       getSubNav(i,ele);
    });
    ele += '</ul>';
    ele += '</li>';

}
```

Comment: Are you having thoughts of implementing the same logic with recursive function? because you are just one step away from making this work using your existing code logic.

Comment: @divine yea, I tried firing the `getSubnav()` and it nothings happening but thanks for the info I'll look how does recursive work. I'll be back :D

Answer (score 1):

CSS fix was also required to let level 2 navigation appear, thanks to [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/ajaypatelaj/pen/prHjD).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.nav').html('');
  var navs = "";

  var nav = [{
      name: "home",
      subNav: []
    },
    {
      name: "shop",
      subNav: [{
          name: "inner1",
          subNav: []
        },
        {
          name: "inner2",
          subNav: [{
            name: "inner3",
            subNav: []
          }, {
            name: "inner4",
            subNav: [{
              name: "inner4-A",
              subNav: []
            }]
          }]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "about",
      subNav: []
    },
    {
      name: "contact",
      subNav: []
    },
  ];

  function createNodeHavingSubNode(src, level2) {

    var node = $('<li/>', {
      class: (level2 === true) ? 'dropdown-submenu' : 'dropdown'
    });

    var anchorTag = $('<a/>', {
      class: 'dropdown-toggle',
      'data-toggle': 'dropdown',
      text: src.name,
      href: '#'
    })

    if (!level2) {
      anchorTag.append('<span class="caret"></span>');
    }

    node.append(anchorTag);

    return node;
  }

  function createSubNavNode(src) {
    var li = $('<li/>');
    var anchor = $('<a/>', {
      href: '/' + src.name,
      text: src.name
    });

    li.append(anchor);

    return li;
  }

  function createSubNodes(data) {

    var element = $('<ul/>', {
      class: 'dropdown-menu'
    });

    $.each(data.subNav, function() {

      var d = this;
      if (typeof d.subNav !== 'undefined' && d.subNav.length > 0) {
        element.append(createNodeHavingSubNode(d, true).append(createSubNodes(d)));
      } else {
        element.append(createSubNavNode(d))
      }

    });

    return element;
  }

  var ul = $('<ul/>').addClass('nav').addClass('navbar-nav');
  $.each(nav, function(n) {

    var node = this;

    if (typeof node.subNav !== 'undefined' && node.subNav.length > 0) {

      ul.append(createNodeHavingSubNode(node).append(createSubNodes(node)));
    } else {
      ul.append(createSubNavNode(node));
    }
  });
  $('.nav').append(ul);


});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     WebSiteName
    </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```